# Oracle Join with operation returning null values

Tags: oracle, join

I'm trying to Right join two table on a column named "compte"
I need to do an addition after. The problem is that some "compte" doesn't exist in one of the table and as a result, the addition return null instead of keeping the based value

Here's the query

```
SELECT t.compte,t.posdev+x.mnt
FROM (

  SELECT compte,SUM(mntdev) as mnt FROM mvtc22
  WHERE compte IN ('11510198451','00610198451','40010198451','40010198453','00610198461','00101980081','00101980094',
  '00101980111','40010198461','40010198462','40010198466','40010198463')
  AND datoper BETWEEN '01/01/22' AND '06/01/22'
  GROUP BY compte
)x

   RIGHT OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT c.compte,c.posdev
  FROM v_sldoper c
  WHERE c.compte IN ('11510198451','00610198451','40010198451','40010198453','00610198461','00101980081','00101980094',
  '00101980111','40010198461','40010198462','40010198466','40010198463')
  AND datpos = '31/12/21'
)t

ON  t.compte = x.compte
```

And the results :

[image: first sub query result]
[image: second sub query result]
[image: Final result]

I'm expecting to keep the results from the second subquery if there's no "compte" in the first subquery.

Thanks In advance,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close, the problem is that in oracle SQL the result of any value + null value is null, so you need to handle potential null values from each column before applying the + operator betwen them.
To solve the issue, you can apply functions like NVL or decode or even CASE WHEN for that purpose.
Below I use NVL function to solve it (I assume t.posdev column cannot contain null values, otherwise apply nvl function to both columns).

```sql
SELECT t.compte, t.posdev + NVL(x.mnt, 0)
FROM (

  SELECT compte,SUM(mntdev) as mnt FROM mvtc22
  WHERE compte IN ('11510198451','00610198451','40010198451','40010198453','00610198461','00101980081','00101980094',
  '00101980111','40010198461','40010198462','40010198466','40010198463')
  AND datoper BETWEEN '01/01/22' AND '06/01/22'
  GROUP BY compte
)x

   RIGHT OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT c.compte,c.posdev
  FROM v_sldoper c
  WHERE c.compte IN ('11510198451','00610198451','40010198451','40010198453','00610198461','00101980081','00101980094',
  '00101980111','40010198461','40010198462','40010198466','40010198463')
  AND datpos = '31/12/21'
)t

ON  t.compte = x.compte
```